# How to add colliders to walls and floor on a Sketchfab .GLTF 3D model, using react-three and react-three/cannon

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, collider, cannon.js

I've started my journey of making an interactive gallery using react-three. I already have the First-Person mechanics figured out and I made a small room to walk and interact. I want to escalate the environment but since I can't make 3D assets, I bought this https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/vr-art-gallery-el5-e3bda3a7086c49f0a84948fd6808bcf4 .

So..what's the logic to add colliders to the walls so I can't cross and floor so I can walk, using react-three/cannon?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea can be achieved by using a nav mesh. There's a popular library for this called [three-pathfinding](https://three-pathfinding.donmccurdy.com/demo/).

The idea with three-pathfinding is that you create a navmesh matching the floor of your scene in a 3D editing tool like blender (which supports gltf by the way) and then loading that into your scene and passing it to three-pathfinding.

You then find out where on the navmesh you've clicked and pass that information to the lib and it will do the rest. The demo code has [this](https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-pathfinding/blob/main/demo/index.html#L152) method that you can use to find where in the scene you are clicking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm using a First-Person approach (WSAD to move) and not a click-to-move, so I have no idea how to make this to work

Comment: @MickaelNeves Oh sorry lol, all the museum demos I remember use mouse controls.

Comment: Anyways, you can do box vs box collisions on the x-z plane since your movement is actually 2D. You can create large blocks that cover areas you don't want players to touch, then export them as one gltf. Loop through the meshes in the gltf and the check  each frame if you are colliding with any of them

Comment: @MickaelNeves did you find a good way to do this? I've been creating floors and walls and stairs manually using blender, and exporting the model separately to my gltf mesh (often a lidar scan of a room). it just takes ages, and surely there must be some ai tool for doing it.. react three rapier can be used for creating colliders, but it creates one big box for a room, which is not ideal. If I drag a gltf into spatial.io, it seems to automatically create them for me, so there must be a way to do it..